# How to throttle clients in a REST API

Tags: api, rest, concurrency, performance

I want to limit clients to an upper limit of number of calls to my REST APIs.
What should I return to inform clients that they've been throttled ?

Amazon S3 is returning HTTP 503 with an error code **SlowDown** to inform clients.

What do you advise ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) documents status 503 as (my emphasis):

> The server is currently unable to
>   handle the request due to a **temporary
>   overloading** or maintenance of the
>   server. The implication is that this
>   is a temporary condition which will be
>   alleviated after some delay. If known,
>   the length of the delay MAY be
>   indicated in a Retry-After header.

it seems a reasonable approach, especially *with* a `Retry-After` header.

Comment: Besides HTTP 503, you can also use HTTP 421 - There are too many connections from your internet address. (But my personal favorite is HTTP 418 - I'm a teapot. :-))

Comment: Twitter is returning a non standard HTTP 420

Comment: RFC 2616 defines none of these 4xx's and says "The 4xx class of status code is intended for cases in which the client seems to have erred", which seems inappropriate here, where the client has done nothing wrong and it's the _server_ that's overloaded.

Comment: In Twitter's case, they have expressedly told clients that there is a 150 request per hour limit. So in a way, the client is breaking the agreement.

Answer (score 0):

For this case it doesn't seem server is overloaded yet , its just a proactive measure to tell the client that you shouldn't send more than x request in some time. HTTP 503 seems to me as over apologetic to the client , while there is no issue with the server yet and still wining about overload to the client. In my humble opinion its kind of client sending too many request and client is at fault so HTTP 421 seems most appropriate HTTP response code for the case.